# Access Knockout ViewModel Data in Sammy route

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, sammy.js

In my Knockout/Sammy SPA, I would like to access ViewModel data in my Sammy route, however, the Sammy route is executed *before* my Knockout behavior. It works on the initial route because I'm setting `self.selectedPage()` equal to the first page, but it doesn't work for subsequent routes...

```
function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.pages = [
        {'linkText': 'Home', 'pageTitle': 'Welcome', 'route': '#/'},
        {'linkText': 'About', 'pageTitle': 'About Us', 'route': '#/about'},
    ]

    self.selectedPage = ko.observable(self.pages[0]);

    self.goToPage = function(page) {
        self.selectedPage(page);
    }

    Sammy(function() {
        this.use(Sammy.Title);
        this.setTitle('The Base Title');

        this.get('#/', function(context) {
            this.title(self.selectedPage().title); //works
        });

        this.get('#/about', function(context) {
            this.title(self.selectedPage().title); //title is undefined
        });
    }).run('#/');
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

I have also tried retrieving the page from the array based on the `route` property of the page and setting `self.selectedPage()` in the Sammy route, which will correctly set the `selectedPage` observable to the right page within the scope of the route event, but when I try to access a property of that view model, like: `self.selectedPage().title`, I get back `undefined`, which is odd, because `console.log(self.selectedPage())` will show the property.

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: How `selectedPage` is releated to Sammy routing in your case? Could you extend your code

Comment: What I would like to be able to do is get information from the ViewModel to pass to functions like Sammy.Title instead of having to do it manually. I've simplified the `pages` array quite a bit in this example. I have since figured out how to set the selectedPage() in the Sammy route, but any time I try to access a view model property like `self.selecedPage().title`, I get `undefined`...can you explain why that might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your page object is defined, it doesn't have a `title` property, but a `pageTitle`. Have you tried

```
this.get('#/about', function(context) {
        this.title(self.selectedPage().pageTitle); 
    });
```

Comment: I finally figured that out on my own, but geebus - what a "derp" moment :)

Comment: I found your question because I was having a similar problem (but not really :). Maybe you have a clue? [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149129/setting-a-knockout-observable-using-sammy-for-routing)